# WPF TextBox text selection issue

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have an issue with selecting part of the text in TextBox. I cannot understand why, I can select just one character at a time and I can select as many as I want with the keyboard (shift+arrow). This is my code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:EditableTextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
            Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:EditableTextBlock}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="bool2Vis" />
                        <local:BooleanToInverseVisibilityConverter x:Key="bool2InverseVis" />
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <TextBox x:Name="textbox"
                             Visibility="{Binding IsInEditMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource bool2Vis}}"
                             TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}"
                             Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" IsHitTestVisible="True" Focusable="True"/>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="textblockContainer"
                                    Visibility="{Binding IsInEditMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource bool2InverseVis}}">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textblock"
                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                   TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}"
                                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                    </ContentControl>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like a custom textbox control. Could you be doing something in code behind of this control? Are you handling any PreviewTestInput or mouse down ?

Comment: I don't handle PreviewTestInput and any mouse event...

Comment: What I meant was there will be something you must be doing in code behind which is missing here in this question.